# Python comparing a list of tuples and a list of clustered words

Tags: python-2.7, list

I need to compare two kind of lists as follow.

List of words with their frequency

```
list_1=[('psicomotricita',6), ('psicomotorio',5) , ('psicomotorie',6),('psicomotore', 7),
        ('bella',1), ('biella',7), ('bello',3),('zorro',4)]
```

List of lists, where every sublist is a cluster of word by their similarity.

```
list_2=[['psicomotricità', 'psicomotorio','psicomotorie','psicomotore']
        ['bella', 'biella', 'bello']
        ['zorro']]
```

So, I need to loop every sublist of the list_2 in order to pick-up the word that compare in the list_1 with the maximum frequency.

The result should be:

```
final_list['psicomotore','biella','zorro']
```

Is there anybody who can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clustering a list of string by their similarity and frequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556184/clustering-a-list-of-string-by-their-similarity-and-frequence)

Comment: Hey @Anony-Mousse, what do you think about the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

After a long struggle (I'm new newbie in python) I solved the problem above.

So, first I converted the list of tuples to a dictionary:

```
d = {t[0]:int(t[1]) for t in list_1}
```

Second, I have created the following function:

```
def SortTuples(list, dict):
final_ls= []
ddd= []
for el in list_2:
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        if key in el:
            ddd.append((key,value))
    z= (max(ddd,key=itemgetter(1))[0])
    final_ls.append(z)
    ddd= []
return final_ls
```

The result is a list with the words whom has the max frequency:

```
Out: ['psicomotore', 'biella', 'zorro']
```

Comment: The purpose of a dictionary is that you don't need to loop over all items and compare the key... what about simply using the dictionary for the max function?